# Using Dependency Properties With Multiple Instances

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I basically have the same problem as this guy here: [Error: " 'Subjects' property was already registered by 'Period' " is raised when more than one control is placed on the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172527/error-subjects-property-was-already-registered-by-period-is-raised-when)

The main difference between us is that I want to subscribe to an event that has access to the local instance when the xaml changes the property.

So I have my UserControl:

```
public partial class BoardSquare : UserControl
{
    public BoardSquare()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Location = new BoardLocation(Int32.MinValue, Int32.MinValue);

        XPositionProperty =
             DependencyProperty.Register("XPosition", typeof(int),
             typeof(BoardSquare), new PropertyMetadata(
                 new PropertyChangedCallback((value, args) => 
                 { 
                     Location.X = (int)args.NewValue;
                     resetBackgroundColorToPosition();
                 })));
        YPositionProperty=
            DependencyProperty.Register("YPosition", typeof(int),
            typeof(BoardSquare), new PropertyMetadata(
                new PropertyChangedCallback((value, args)=>
                {
                    Location.Y = (int)args.NewValue;
                    resetBackgroundColorToPosition();
                })));
    }

    private void resetBackgroundColorToPosition()
    {
        this.Background = (Brush)(new ColorEnumToBrushesConverter()).Convert(Location.GetSquareColor(), typeof(BlackWhiteColor), null, null);
    }

    public readonly DependencyProperty XPositionProperty;
    public readonly DependencyProperty YPositionProperty;

    public int XPosition
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)GetValue(XPositionProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(XPositionProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public int YPosition 
    { 
        get
        {
            return (int)GetValue(YPositionProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(YPositionProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public BoardLocation Location { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my XAML:

```
<local:BoardSquare Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" XPosition="3" YPosition="0"/>
<local:BoardSquare Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" XPosition="4" YPosition="0"/>
```

From what I understand, the solution is to make XPositionProperty static and then register it in a static constructor. My problem then is I can't access the local instance of the class when my PropertyChangeCallback event happens.

How can I set the property in the XAML and still get an on property changed event in the C# code?

Is there a better solution than dependency properties?

---

Below is the working code of BoardSquare after I implemented the answer.

```
    public partial class BoardSquare : UserControl
{
    static BoardSquare()
    {
        XPositionProperty =
             DependencyProperty.Register("XPosition", typeof(int),
             typeof(BoardSquare), new PropertyMetadata(
                 new PropertyChangedCallback((objectInstance, args) =>
                 {
                     BoardSquare boardSquare = (BoardSquare)objectInstance;
                     boardSquare.Location.X = (int)args.NewValue;
                     boardSquare.resetBackgroundColorToPosition();
                 })));
        YPositionProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("YPosition", typeof(int),
            typeof(BoardSquare), new PropertyMetadata(
                new PropertyChangedCallback((objectInstance, args) =>
                {
                    BoardSquare boardSquare = (BoardSquare)objectInstance;
                    boardSquare.Location.Y = (int)args.NewValue;
                    boardSquare.resetBackgroundColorToPosition();
                })));
    }

    public BoardSquare()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Location = new BoardLocation(Int32.MinValue, Int32.MinValue);


    }

    private void resetBackgroundColorToPosition()
    {
        this.Background = (Brush)(new ColorEnumToBrushesConverter()).Convert(Location.GetSquareColor(), typeof(BlackWhiteColor), null, null);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty XPositionProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty YPositionProperty;

    public int XPosition
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)GetValue(XPositionProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(XPositionProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public int YPosition 
    { 
        get
        {
            return (int)GetValue(YPositionProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(YPositionProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public BoardLocation Location { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **first argument** of PropertyChangedCallback **is the local instance** (btw. you better name it *obj* than *value* to avoid confusion). You have to cast this `DependencyObject` to `BoardSquare` and that's all.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty XPositionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("XPosition", typeof(int), typeof(BoardSquare),
                                new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback((obj, args) => {
                                    BoardSquare bs = obj as BoardSquare;
                                    bs.Location.X = (int)args.NewValue;
                                    bs.resetBackgroundColorToPosition();
                                })));
```

Comment: Very nice I feel stupid for not realizing that obj was my instance. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to override already WPF certificate property with your own. I don't think that's necessary here. If XPosition is already WPF certificate property, all you have to do is create a property in your usercontrol with getter/setter with setter calling INotifypropertychanged. you don't need dependency property in this case unless you want only same name but behave differently, and why do you want that?.

Comment: I'm not trying to override an existing property. XPosition and YPosition could be called something else. Without the dependency property I can't assign values to them in the XAML. I would kindof prefer to stay away from a setter, because things look cleaner this way, but I may be forced that route.